# How to identify unique dictionary key of type <RateIdentifier> with certains members equal to something?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary `_customRates` with keys of type `RateIdentifier` and values of type `customRate`.  Type `T` looks like this:

```
public RateIdentifier(int id, 
         string name,
         Currency currency1,
         Currency currency2)
```

Now, I have a particular `currency1` and `currency2`, and I want to check whether there exists a `RateIdentifier` in my dictionary with these specified currencies, and if so return the key (if not return some default). I know that if such a key exists it will be the *only* key that has this particular `currency1` and `currency2` (*<sup>i.e.</sup> the two currencies ensure uniqueness of a particular key*).

I'm finding this difficult because although I know how to use `.Where` on my dictionary, it doesn't seem to be an appropriate solution since I know I will only have at most one such key, so it seems overkill to check the entire dictionary every time as some of these dictionaries are particularly huge.

Comment: How is the dictionary comparing the keys for equality? Is it using the same criteria you're using?  And you should not use `T` as the name of a type.  not only is it standard convention to use as a generic argument, it's just not informative of what the type actually represents.

Comment: @Servy I updated the type to reflect what it actually is, thanks for that. And the dictionary is comparing the `id`s of the keys for equality I believe.

Comment: Does `RateIdentifier` implement `Equals/GetHashCode` in a way that encodes these equality rules? If not you should supply an `IEqualityComparer<RateIdentifier>` to the dictionary which does. Then you can simply use `ContainsKey` on the dictionary rather than iterate through all the keys.

Comment: I'm going to override Equals and GetHashCode such that they compare the two currencies for equality, then use the solution outlined below by Henrik Igen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault`, if overriding GetHashCode() and Equals() is not a possibility:

```
var myStuff = _customRates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.currency1 == myCurrency1 && x.Key.currency2 == myCurrency2);
```

However, you can (and possibly should) also override GetHashCode() and Equals() on your key type (if you haven't already) and make them return the same hash code for the same currencies. This way, you can use the standard facilities of the dictionary:

```
// Assume GetHashCode and Equals are overridden
var myStuff = _customRates[new RateIdentifier() { currency1 = myCurrency1, currency2 = myCurrency2 }];
```

When looking up values, the `Dictionary` will first calculate the hash code (using `GetHashCode`) of the specified key and search for that. If multiple elements in the `Dictionary` have the same hash code, `Equals` will be called to determine which one matches the key. This means that, even if you do not have the specific key object that was used when you added a value to your dictionary, you can still construct a new key.

Comment: See `IEquatable<T>`, and note that if a type implements such where `T` is itself, `Dictionary` will pick it up and use that `Equals` method instead of having to type check in an override of `Object.Equals`